# Как восстановить настройки роутера на linux?

Tags: wifi, роутер, linux

Как восстановить настройки роутера на linux?

Comment: позовите экстрасенсов!

Answer (score 3):

Для того, что бы получить помощь, Вам необходимо описать:

1. что у Вас за роутер (отдельное устройство или еще один компьютер, который выполняет ф-ции роутера);
2. Какая ОС на роутере;
3. имеете ли Вы к нему доступ (знаете ли пароль администратора, доступ через web-интерфейс, ssh, telnet  или физически);
4. Что Вы хотите настроить/восстановить...

В противном случае, Вам действительно потребуется ясновидящий, поскольку нам Вы ничего не рассказали.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ-перезагрузить!Ну тогда придется,настраивать все заново.Если отвалился нет(такое бывает)1ым делом звоните провайдеру,и говорите о своей проблеме,еще не плохо бы знать свой ip,маску,и dns-что бы можно было прописать их в ручную,при необходимости!Если прошили,обратно дороги нет.